# Want someone to review my Helmholtz coil design to see if I am missing something obvious before I fabricate it?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetics, induction, magnetic-flux

I am planning to construct a Helmholtz coil and wanted electrical engineers to take a look just so I know I am not overlooking anything.
The max field strength I am looking for is 200 Gauss. I ran some COMSOL simulations and found that I can get slightly above this field strength by[image] having 1120 turns of 21 AWG copper wire. The diameter of the coils is 22 cm this is to get a work space between the coils of about 10 cm. I am using copper wire rated for 200 deg C. I plan to power these coils using two independent DC power supplies with 60V 2.5 A to avoid any issues (Let me know if that is overkill?) Also these 1120 turns are divided in 10 layers of 112 turns on a wooden frame in case anyone was wondering. I have attached my images of the comsol simulation (only the region between 150-250mm is within the bounds of the coil). Do let me know if anyone see's any obvious issues with this design.

[image]

Comment: have you computed the resistance of the coils?  60V seems like quite a lot of headroom

Comment: 33 ohm DC resistance

Comment: Going to get rather toasty. At 180°C 330W per coil assuming your 33Ω is at 20°C.

Comment: 33 ohm at 25 deg C we do not plan to use it for long intervals at a time maybe 15 min intervals. Do you think its cutting it too close to the 200 deg rating of the wire?

Comment: About 3 kilograms of copper, so about 4000 joules per degree, at 330W and 180 degrees it looks to be good for more than 20 minutes.